# Put degree symbol in html input tag

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

How do I put degree symbol in a textbox using javascript ?

Comment: Do you mean put it in as styling (so as the user types there is a degree symbol at the end of their text)?

Comment: HTML code for degree symbol is `&#176;` or `&deg;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the html entities code.

```
<input value='&#176;'></input>
```